# Get test set feature vectors from Pipeline in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to debug my ML model and I want to see which features are used/activated in each observation in my test set. So I need to get the transformed matrix with the features **after** the vectorization, feature selection steps in the pipeline.
First of all here is the pipeline:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('fu', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=[
            ('val', Pipeline([
                ('ext', FeatureExtractor(feat_type="valence")),
                ('vect', DictVectorizer()),
            ])),
            ('bot', Pipeline([
                ('ext', FeatureExtractor(feat_type="bot", term="word", pos=False, negation=True)),
                ('vec', CountVectorizer(min_df=3, max_df=0.9, lowercase=False)),
                ("fs", SelectKBest(chi2, k=8000)),
                ('bin', Binarizer()),
                ('trans', TfidfTransformer(sublinear_tf=True, smooth_idf=True, use_idf=True)),
            ]))
        ],
    )),
    ('stats', FeatureStats()),
    ("fs", MaxAbsScaler()),
    ('classifier', svm.LinearSVC(C=.5)),
])
```

So I read [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.transform) and it seems that I can use `transform` to get the transformed matrix (which is now deprecated, but anyway...). And i tried doing this:

```
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
transformed = pipeline.transform(X_test)
y_predicted = pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

But I have a problem.

As you can see I select the the 8000 most discriminating features so the matrix that goes in and out of the classifier must be `N x 8000`. But the problem is that `transformed` is `M x 3012` (N=training examples, M=test examples).

In order to verify that the pipeline is working correctly I put `FeatureStats`, a transformer that simply prints the length of the feature vectors, right before the classifier, and it prints 8000.

```
class FeatureStats(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        print("size = ", X.shape[1])
        return X

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
```

Why does `pipeline.transform(X_test)` return a smaller matrix? Am I missing something?

Comment: The 'transform()' method of LinearSVC says "Reduce X to its most important features.". Probably 3012 is the number of features kept after selecting the most important features calculated by the SVM.

Comment: If you know, can you please tell how you get feature name as well. I was looking to get Dict of feature_name and 0 or 1. I can post a question if you like.